# Can I use httprequest to post a file automatically, in the same way I might with a regular upload?

Tags: post, file-io, asp-classic, multipartform-data

I'm stuck on something that (I think) should be quite simple, but I can't work out how to do it. I can't find any information either here on SO or on Google.

We have a web app that takes data from our site and automatically POSTS this to another API.

We'd like to send over a binary file also - for example, we'd grab the file from a local URL and POST it's contents over to the other site.

Could anybody point me in the right direction for this?  For example, would I need to embed the file URL in the data somehow and POST as multipart/form-data?

Comment: To another API? Where/to whom are you posting the data to?

Comment: It's a job board. We're trying to post over a resume /cv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created these Classic ASP function to POST a file to another server. Hopefully it will help you too.

```
Function PostDocument(intDocumentID, binFile, strFilename, strContentType)
Dim objHttp, strBoundary, strRequestStart, strRequestEnd, binPost
Dim objStream

strBoundary = "---------------------------9849436581144108930470211272"

Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

strRequestStart = "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf &_
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""id""" & vbCrlf &_
    vbCrlf &_
    intDocumentID & vbCrlf &_
    vbCrlf &_
    "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf &_
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & strFilename & """" & vbCrlf &_
    "Content-Type: " & strContentType & vbCrlf &_
    vbCrlf

strRequestEnd = vbCrLf & "--" & strBoundary & "--"

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.Type = adTypeBinary '1
objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite '3
objStream.Open
objStream.Write StringToBinary(strRequestStart)
objStream.Write binFile
objStream.Write StringToBinary(strRequestEnd)
objStream.Position = 0

binPost = objStream.Read

Response.Write binPost

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing

objHttp.Open "POST", "(url removed)", False, "(username removed)", "(password removed)"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=""" & strBoundary & """"
objHttp.Send binPost

PostDocument = objHttp.ResponseText

Set objHttp = Nothing
End Function

Function StringToBinary(toConvert)
Dim objStream, data

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"
objStream.Type = adTypeText '2
objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite '3
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText toConvert

objStream.Position = 0
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary '1
StringToBinary = objStream.Read

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: (3 days later) almost there.....  can I ask... what is going on with the 2 Content Disposition headers in strRequestStart?

Comment: First one is for a form field (intDocumentId - change for whatever you need to pass in addition to the file), second one is for the file itself. You will need more if you want to pass more than one field or file in the same request.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me after all that time. :)  Does that mean if I'm just posting the file itself I can ignore the first one?

Comment: I 90% got it to work, but the files I'm posting appear to be corrupt when I download them from the destination. Is there any chance you could take a look at the code posted here and tell me if there's anything obvious I've done wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155243/what-is-wrong-with-this-httprequest-posting-a-binary-file

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to get back here to help until now. Were you able to sort out the problem?

Comment: Thank you, and almost! Somewhere I am getting extra null/zero bytes being added onto the end of my posted files, but I can't figure out where this is coming from.  I figured it deserved an separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341803/exact-same-file-and-code-so-why-does-the-binary-of-my-docx-file-always-end-diff  (check the update at the bottom)